# Send ajax request without encoding url

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch

I am trying to write a javascript-jquery client for elasticsearch, I am trying to send a PUT request to elasticsearch cluster using jquery ajax like so :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9200/a/b/docId 2014/04/04" ,
    data: JSON.stringify(document),
    type:'PUT',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType:'json',
    complete:function(data){

    }
});
```

When this request is processed, the url is being encoded. So the elasitcsearch cluster responds with a 400 (Bad Request) as there would be characeters like % / in the url. So how can I send an ajax request without encoding the url? Or better, how can I index documents with id as such in an elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: What's wrong with encoding them? If you're really against it, then I would recommend changing the `/`s in the date to `-`s, and simply remove the ` ` (space), thus jamming the two values together. The ID only matters as a way to directly reference the document. If you plan on storing them this way, then you should probably store those values in the document itself. Of course, you can always automatically index based on the [`_timestamp` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html), which may allow you to avoid the date altogether?

Comment: FYI, URL encoded values [should work](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/681), but it looks like there might be a [regression](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2903), so ideally changing the `/` to `-` should fix your issue altogther.

Comment: I cannot change id of documents, it is being used by another application.